# Did the early church believe that Jesus was celibate?

Tags: life-of-jesus, church-history, early-church, church-fathers

Jesus Christ in the gospels was never married nor did he ever have children and it is believed historically that Jesus himself was celibate but did any of the Early Church Fathers believe that Jesus Christ was celibate?

Comment: related [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3515/could-jesus-have-been-married)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, at least two of the Church Fathers refer to Jesus as being not only celibate but a lifelong virgin.

- **Tertullian c 200, On Monogamy 3** - the Lord Himself opens the kingdoms of the heavens to eunuchs, as being Himself, withal, a virgin; to whom looking, the apostle also — himself too for this reason abstinent — gives the preference to continence.
- **St. Methodius of Olympus c. 300. Banquet of Ten Virgins 1.4**
  It was reserved for the Lord alone to be the first to teach this doctrine [eunuchs for the Kingdom]... He who was first and chief of priests, of prophets, and of angels, should also be saluted as first and chief of virgins. For in old times man was not yet perfect, and for this reason was unable to receive perfection, which is virginity.